# Transaction-type for local postgres tool?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

I have a local application (no JEE server) that shall use postgres at the end.
I'd like to chose `Hibernate` as my database framework. I'm now creating the `persistence.xml`, and wonder which transaction-type I should chose: JTA or RESOURCE_LOCAL, or none?

`<persistence-unit name="travelport" transaction-type="JTA">`

Further I'd like to use the Hibernate EntityManager in my application. Can I have my application manage the transaction itself somehow (any framework)? Or do I always have to open, commit and close the transactions myself when not using an application server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only need the `JTA` transaction type if you're running in an EE environment, so definitely choose `RESOURCE_LOCAL`.

As for transaction management, have a look at [Spring Transaction Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) - I won't repeat the good examples in that link here, but feel free to post follow-up questions if needs be :-)

And don't forget DB pooling as well ([DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/), [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) etc).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

For a SE application, you should use `RESOURCE_LOCAL` and manage the transaction by yourself.

Automatic transaction management would require the beans/services to have a managed lifecycle and a possibility to plug in into that lifecycle.

I am not aware of a readymade lifecycle framework for Java (Spring is a good option for servlet containers, but be aware of all the goods it brings to the table in addition to the bean lifecycle).